# Changing a variable from a different form on VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

Iv'e been creating a game on VB for a school assignment and I am having trouble creating a difficulty setting. I have four buttons on my title screen in which you can choose a difficulty. when you click one of the buttons it's supposed to add to the "speed" variable on the main game. I've tried a few methods and it still doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code that I am using.

**Main game variables:**

```
Public speed As Single = 5
Dim xVel As Single = Math.Cos(speed) * speed
Dim yVel As Single = Math.Sin(speed) * speed
```

**Title screen code (difficulty select):**

```
Private Sub btnPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click
    gameMain.Show()

    If btnEasy.Enabled = False Then
        gameMain.speed = 5
    End If

    If btnMedium.Enabled = False Then
        gameMain.speed = gameMain.speed + 2
    End If

    If btnHard.Enabled = False Then
        gameMain.speed = gameMain.speed + 5
    End If

    If btnInsane.Enabled = False Then
        gameMain.speed = gameMain.speed + 10
    End If

End Sub
```

So when you click a button it gets disabled and changes color. when you start the game, if one of the buttons is disabled its supposed to add the corresponding amount to the "speed" variable.

I've also tried putting similar code on the Main game form and that also didn't work.
I'm trying to keep the code as simple as possible as I am still an amateur at VB.

Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: So what's happening right now? `gameMain.speed` is always set to 5?

Comment: Have you debugged through the code to see that it actually gets executed? Maybe `gameMain.Show()` takes execution away from the rest of your method. Try moving that to the last line and see if it helps.

Comment: it says there's no errors and putting it on the last line didn't work either.

Comment: Its a bit of a hack but can you move the speed variable into a global module, make it a global static variable and see if that works?

Comment: I've never used a global module before but i'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: The module method worked, it works great now, thank you!

Comment: @NeilKennedy : Please post solution as an answer and ask the author to accept it, if it really helped. This would save the time of community who are looking for un-answered questions.

Answer (score 4):

Your code only changes the "speed" field, it doesn't re-calculate the values for xVel and yVel.

You solve this problem by making speed a *property* instead of a field.  The property setter can adjust the velocity vector:

```
Private _speed As Single
Private xVel As Single
Private yVel As Single
Private angle As Single

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Speed = 5
End Sub

Public Property Speed() As Single
    Get
        Return _speed
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Single)
        _speed = value
        xVel = _speed * Math.Cos(angle)
        yVel = _speed * Math.Sin(angle)
    End Set
End Property
```

You'll need to work on `angle` next.

Comment: I fixed the problem by using a global module, but the point you made about the angle is interesting. I might look into it, thanks

Comment: Well, don't do that.  Global variables rarely ever solved a problem, they just add new ones.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @AYK I'm posting my comment above as an answer so we can close out this question....

Its a bit of a hack but can you move the speed variable into a global module, make it a global static variable and see if that works?